# Is there a way to configure MediaWikis in such a way that a MediaWiki will *not* replace underscores by spaces?

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a way to configure MediaWiki installations in such a way that MediaWiki installations will *not* replace underscores by spaces?

(And if so *how* can this be configured for a particular namespace?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. `{{DISPLAYTITLE:_foo_bar}}` can be used iff the specific title you intend to show - here: `_foo_bar` - would result in the regular page title such as `foo bar`.

Due to some design decisions MediaWiki will replace an underscore in the regular title by a space (and simplify two consecutive spaces into a single one). Now with `{{DISPLAYTITLE:.....}}` you can force MediaWiki to display the title you intended instead of the simplified one MediaWiki will use after processing your input. So you *can* name a MediaWiki page title `_foo_bar` though MediaWiki will internally register such a page as `foo bar`.

For every page where you want such a specific title instead of the default one you have to provide a `{{DISPLAYTITLE:.....}}` separately.

This feature was not part of the first releases of MediaWiki.